# Simplification of expression $\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{x}\bar{y}z+x\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{y}z$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Here are my steps:
$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{x}\bar{y}z+x\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{y}z$
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{x}\bar{y}z+x\bar{y}\bar{z}+(x\bar{y}z+x\bar{y}z)$$ Used Idempotent law  and rearranged the equation
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + (\bar{x}\bar{y}z+x\bar{y}z)+(x\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{y}z)$$ factoring
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{y}z(\bar{x}+x)+x\bar{y}(\bar{z}+z)$$Complement law
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{y}z(1)+x\bar{y}(1) + \bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} $$ Used Idempotont law again
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{y}(x + \bar{x}+z+\bar{z}) $$factoring
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{y}(1+1) $$Complement Law and Tautology
$$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + \bar{y}1$$Used Identity law on y
$$\bar{y}(1+\bar{x}\bar{z})$$Tautology
$$\bar{y}$$
However I need x and z values.
$$\bar{y}+\bar{x}x+z\bar{z}$$
The question states that I need to find the minimization of the original expression, as the sum of three terms.
Is my steps valid?

Comment: Hard to see what you did from step to step. Especially the last step when you suddenly arrive at just "y-bar". Also: what is the line right after "However I need..."? Is it the answer you're supposed to get to, i.e. your problem is an exercise with that line given as the answer?

Comment: @coffeemath The question states that I need to find the minimization of the original expression, as the sum of three terms.
Sorry if the steps are unclear, I will add some comments next to them now

Comment: Good to insert the rule used for each step. Also there can be no valid rule to arrive at y-bar. The starting expression is not equivalent to y-bar.

Comment: You still did not say whether the 3-term expression of the last display is the book answer, or is just one of your steps.

Comment: @coffeemath The final expression is my answer for the question. Sadly the book doesnt have an answer key

Comment: What are $x,y,z $? What is the bar operation?

Comment: @P.Lawrence   x, y, and z are boolean variables and the bar operation stands for complement/negation

Comment: Let me use $x'$ for $\bar{x}$, as it is easier to typeset. There is a point in which you have the expression $$x'y'z'+y'z(x+x')+xy'(z+z')$$ which simplifies to $x'y'z'+y'z+xy'$, but then you add another $x'y'z'$, and claim that by idempotency you get another expression which I really can't see how. But $$x'y'z'+y'z+xy'=y'(x+x'z'+z)$$ and $$x+x'z'+z=x(z+z')+x'z'+z=xz+z+(x+x')z'=xz+z+z'=1.$$ Hence the original expression simplifies to $y'$ (I just can't match your steps to the justifications.)

Comment: @amrsa I will try simplifying it again.

I also tried finding the simplification using a karnaugh map, and reached the same answer = y'

But the truth table for the original expression and y' dont match, so I cannot present that as the final answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600582/karnaugh-map-for-the-expression-barx-bary-barz-barx-baryzx-bary

Comment: @Dravid They **must** match. Or else we did something wrong!

Comment: Note that the expression is simply $$y' (xz + xz' + x'z + x'z') = y' (x + x') (z + z') = y'.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your simplification process is correct, and so is your result $\bar y$.
2. If your truth tables don't match then you probably made a mistake computing the truth tables. I can't check those because you haven't posted them.
3. Your last statement "The question states that I need to find the minimization of the original expression, as the sum of three terms." is very strange since the expression simplifies to just 1 term. I realize you can awkwardly rewrite it as 3, but I would expect whoever assigned this question would not ask for 3 terms if the expression simplifies to just $\bar y$. It makes me think you should double-check for mistakes in copying down the initial expression to be simplified. (That could also explain why your truth tables aren't matching up.)

Comment: I just realized I might be inputting the truth tables incorrectly. For the initial expression, the truth table has 3 boolean variables ( 8 rows), and the final simplification $\bar{y}$ has just 1 variable (2 rows). Do I have to include x and z values to the $\bar{y}$ truth table too?

Comment: @Dravid You've shown the original expression is equivalent to the three-variable truth table $\bar y$. We're viewing $\bar y$ as a function of 3 variables, so it will produce a 2x2x2 truth table that just doesn't depend on $x$ or $z$ at all.

Comment: I don't understand how $\bar{y}$ can have 2x2x2 truth table. Would the columns be like $y$, $\bar{y}$? Sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: @Dravid $x$ could be true or false. $y$ could be true or false. $z$ could be true or false. Therefore $f(x,y,z) = \bar y$ has 8 different inputs which need to be shown in that table, even though the output doesn't depend on $x$ or $z$.

Comment: That really helps, thank you so much David!